# What is the meaning of "unsigned", "signed" and "imaginary" numbers in the Go spec?

Tags: go

In Go there is one section for numeric types, but I'm not really clear about some of the definitions. What it means "**unsigned**", "the set of all **signed**", "imaginary parts" in this context?

```
uint8       the set of all unsigned  8-bit integers (0 to 255)
uint16      the set of all unsigned 16-bit integers (0 to 65535)
uint32      the set of all unsigned 32-bit integers (0 to 4294967295)
uint64      the set of all unsigned 64-bit integers (0 to 18446744073709551615)

int8        the set of all signed  8-bit integers (-128 to 127)
int16       the set of all signed 16-bit integers (-32768 to 32767)
int32       the set of all signed 32-bit integers (-2147483648 to 2147483647)
int64       the set of all signed 64-bit integers (-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807)

float32     the set of all IEEE-754 32-bit floating-point numbers
float64     the set of all IEEE-754 64-bit floating-point numbers

complex64   the set of all complex numbers with float32 real and imaginary parts
complex128  the set of all complex numbers with float64 real and imaginary parts

byte        alias for uint8
rune        alias for int32
```

Reference: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types

Comment: There are pretty foundational concepts of computer science, so you should probably take a look at [the definition of integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29), [the definition of floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic), and [the definition of complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_data_type) data types over at wikipedia and come back if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var x complex128 = complex(1, 2) // 1+2i`

max values for a complex number:`complex128(1.7976931348623157e+308 + 1.7976931348623157e+308 i)`

if you familiar with complex number then you can understand it. else here `i` = `root of (-1)` or `i^2 = -1`

unsigned means only positive numbers and 0.

uint64 range `0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615`

uint32 range `0 to 4,294,967,295`

and the `set of signed` means the total number range of negative to positive

Comment: Thanks for your answer @H.R. Emon, what about imaginary parts?

Comment: for complex number's both real and imaginary part the max value is  same as max float64 size. `MaxFloat64             = 1.797693134862315708145274237317043567981e+308 // 2**1023 * (2**53 - 1) / 2**52`